# Border radius circle

Tags: html, css

I've this code :

```css
span p {
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <p>25</p>
    <p>08</p>
</span>
```

I want to make a perfect circle on my span. I try a `border-radius: 50%;` but it does not work.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this by giving the span a fixed width and height:

```css
span p {
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <p>25</p>
    <p>08</p>
</span>
```

Comment: add line-height of equal to height - to keep the text vertically in middle

Answer (score 5):

You need a predefined width and height on the span to be able to make it round.

```css
span p {
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    padding-left:10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <p>25</p>
    <p>08</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `line-height` and `width`:

```
span {
    background-color: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.
HTML:

```
<span>
        <p>25</p>
        </span>

        <span>
        <p>08</p>
        </span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**border-radius: 50% and padding**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let el = document.querySelector('#wrapper .container');
  
  setTimeout(() => (el.style.marginTop = '20px'), 500);
}, false);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
  0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
  0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: margin-top 650ms ease-out, box-shadow 120ms, transform 120ms;
  will-change: margin-top, box-shadow, transform;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper .container:hover:not(:active) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
  0 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 
  0 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

#wrapper .container:active {
  transform: scale(1.4) translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 11px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
  0 18px 28px 2px rgba(0, 0,0 , 0.14), 
  0 7px 34px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <span>10</span>

    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you incorrectly nested `paragraph` elements inside of `span`, which is against [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html), as `span` is being defined there as an element, which **Content Model** is described as **Phrasing Content**, and that:

*Most elements that are categorized as [**Phrasing Content**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content.*

And because `paragraph` element doesn't belong to **Phrasing Content** list, you can use [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) instead of [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) for this purpose, only if you care to be semantically correct.

So coming back to your problem, it can be rewritten as so:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>25</p>
    <p>08</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
div {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Where general rule for achieving the circle by using `border radius` set to `50%`, is that you need to make sure that content of such element has the same width and height. You can get that by fixing these values in your `css`.

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqLrxcte/) presenting that.